Session closes on PostBack (ASP.NET)
I focused the problem to this piece of code:
Private sub Page_Load(byval sender as system.object, byval e as system.eventArgs) handles myBase.Load
if (not IsPostBack) then
  'Do nothing
end if

If (session("IsAlive")=1) then
  WriteToLog("true")
Else
  WriteToLog("false")
End if

When I entry to the page_load in the first time (not on PostBack), it writes "true". But when I entry in the second time (when click on button or dropDownList), it writes "false".
Its a program that works fine on another server, and now we have a new server to which I copied the programs and configured them in iis similar to the old server.
In the config file I have
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />

as specified on the old server.
Also, when I run the program from the server, everything works fine. The problem only happens when running from the local station (on any computer).
Please help

Have you tried setting a breakpoint to check the value of session("IsAlive") yet? Where is that value being set?

The value is set at the begining of the program on "onInit". When I run the program from the local machine it works fine, so in breakpoint session("IsAlive") returns true. Thats why I wrote the value to log file (then it writes false)

This suggests some un-handeled error. Remember, with a error, then often app-pool will re-start, and a re-start blows out the current session. So, your posted code is not sufficent to re-produce this error.  Try building a test page with your above code, or post a fully working sample in which the issue can be re-produced. During development, I use in-proc, but my production config uses SQL server based sessions. They are 100x more robust, since un-handled errors and app pool restarts don't re-set session. (so, it becomes very reliable as opposed to often being rather flakey with in-proc).
